# Margins not aligned for tablet sized device, media query

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Margins not maintained well when media queries are applied for tablet view i.e medium size devices.
The 3rd block which is coded to acquire 100% width when in medium size but the margins doesn't align well.
Why does the third paragraph doesn't align perfectly below the first two blocks.
Please help.[Check the medium size device output, 3rd box not aligned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLeuL.jpg)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #808080;
  width: 90%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: black;
}


/* Simple Responsive Framework. */

.row {
  width: 100%;
}


/********** Large devices only **********/

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/********** Medium devices only **********/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  /********** Small devices only **********/
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-sm-1,
    .col-sm-2,
    .col-sm-3,
    .col-sm-4,
    .col-sm-5,
    .col-sm-6,
    .col-sm-7,
    .col-sm-8,
    .col-sm-9,
    .col-sm-10,
    .col-sm-11,
    .col-sm-12 {
      float: left;
    }
    .col-sm-1 {
      width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-sm-2 {
      width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-sm-3 {
      width: 25%;
    }
    .col-sm-4 {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-sm-5 {
      width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-sm-6 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .col-sm-7 {
      width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-sm-8 {
      width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-sm-9 {
      width: 74.99%;
    }
    .col-sm-10 {
      width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-sm-11 {
      width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-sm-12 {
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title style="font-size: 125%">Module 2 Solution</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="module2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Our menu</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <p></p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think it is because the 3rd div of paragraph has the same parent's element as the previous 2 divs.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and you are missing one thing. For tablet devices you should increase width of third paragraph to 95%.